# ngx formly hybrid of radio & select

Tags: angular, ngx-formly

I am using https://formly.dev/guide/getting-started.

Requirement : looking for a FormlyFieldConfig which can help me create a form similar to the screenshot attached.
Which is basically a hybrid of radio button and select. Can it be done using formly ?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKUEt.png)

Regards,
Sathya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

someone just asked similar request on `gitter`, so the solution is to either create a custom field type (https://formly.dev/guide/custom-formly-field) or define 2 fields https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uw9fkq

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you would like to make this but this doesn't look like something that needs a package have you tried using angular reactive forms?
you just have to bind the value of radio inputs to a property and also bind value of the select box to the third input